# Multiple instances of PHP with Apache2

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I have a simple problem. I would like to run multiple PHP scripts from a single host.

Here is the test script:
 `<?php
        sleep(10);
        echo 'Done ', date('H:i:s');`

There are two cases:

1. When two different hosts run this script, they finish at the same time.
2. When one host runs this script, there is a 10 second difference between the results, so the script started later, took 20 seconds to execute.

How can I achieve the same result as in the first case?

**EDIT:**
The second case only occurs when the host, executable file, and the browser also the same. I can run it at the same time from different browsers or the same script in differently named files (like *test1.php* and *test2.php*).

Comment: Correction: The client **requests** the script -> telling the server to **execute** it.

Comment: Not gonna happen on one host.

Comment: Any way to "hack" it?

Comment: You should check Reverse Proxy: https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/glossary/reverse-proxy.html